# In a sas compare, output only differences and new records

Tags: sas

In a compare with `id`, how can I output only the difference and the new records
but not the old records no more present?

Example, suppose I have two tables:

mybase:

```
    key other
    1   Ann
    3   Ann
    4   Charlie
    5   Emily
```

and mycompare:

```
    key other
    2   Bill
    3   Charlie
    4   Charlie
```

running:

```
    proc compare data=mybase
        compare=mycompare
        outnoequal
        outdif
        out=myoutput
        listvar
        outcomp
        outbase
        method = absolute 
        criterion = 0.0001  
    ;
    id key;
    run;
```

I get a table "myoutput" like this:

```
    type    obs key other
    base    1   1   Ann
    compare 1   2   Bill
    base    2   3   Ann
    compare 2   3   Charlie
    dif     2   3   XXXXXXX
    base    4   5   Emily
```

I would like to have this:

```
    type    obs key other
    compare 1   2   Bill
    base    2   3   Ann
    compare 2   3   Charlie
    dif     2   3   XXXXXXX
```

Comment: I don't see an option for that in PROC COMPARE.  Might be forced to add a pre-processing step where you merge MyBase and MyCompare by ID, and delete any records from MyBase where the ID is not in MyCompare.  Then you can run PROC COMPARE with the updated version of MyBase.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you, I hoped there was :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for your example.  I think you want to output records that are not matched in base and any records that match and have differences.

```
data mybase;
   input key other $;
   cards;
    1   Ann
    3   Ann
    4   Charlie
    5   Emily
;;;;
data mycompare;
   input key other $;
   cards;
    2   Bill
    3   Charlie
    4   Charlie
;;;;

proc compare data=mybase
     compare=mycompare
     outnoequal
     outdif
     out=myoutput
     listvar
     outcomp
     outbase
     method = absolute 
     criterion = 0.0001  
 ;
 id key;
 run;
proc print;
   run;
data test;
   set myoutput;
   by key;
   if (first.key and last.key) and _type_ eq 'BASE' then delete;
   run;
proc print;
   run;


Obs    _TYPE_     _OBS_    key    other

 1     COMPARE      1       2     Bill
 2     BASE         2       3     Ann
 3     COMPARE      2       3     Charlie
 4     DIF          1       3     XXXXXXX.
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly and is independent on inputs, as I was looking for, thank you!